# If $G$ is a graph with exactly one vertex of odd degree, does G have both an Eurelian trail and an Eurelian tour?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I believe the answer must be yes, because I'm having a difficult time finding a counterexample that contains only one vertex of odd degree. So I need to figure out how to prove this.

All I've got so far is the template for my proof:

> Proof. 
>   Suppose $G$ is a graph with exactly one vertex of odd degree.
>   ...
>   Therefore, $G$ has both an Eurelian trail and an Eurelian tour.

Can anyone give me some pointers in where to go next? Hints are perfectly fine, but I prefer to discuss them to assure my understanding of the problem.

EDIT: Is this problem vacuously true? I don't think it's possible to have a graph with exactly one vertex of odd degree...

Comment: How many graphs with exactly one vertex of odd degree have you already examined?

Comment: I just made an edit - I don't think it's possible. I can prove this using the Handshake Theorem. If we sum up all of the vertex degrees that are even, we will get an even number. Then we add the odd degree and make the sum odd. That means $|E|$ can't be an integer. Therefore the statement is vacuously true, because a graph of this form does not exist. Right?

Comment: @dewick49: right!

Answer (score 0):

This answer is more comprehensive!

**Proposition:**
A connected graph has an Eulerian tour if and only if every vertex has even degree.

**proof**
Since the Eulerian tour needs to visit  every edge exactly once, then whenever the Eulerian tour enters a vertex by an edge, it must also leaves the vertex by an another edge.

**Proposition:**
A connected  graph has an Eulerian trail if and only if there exists exactly two vertices with odd degree.   Any Eulerian trail  starts at  one of vertices with the odd degree and end at the other.